# Convergence of the series $\sum \sqrt{a_n}/n$ given that $\sum a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been dealing with this problem for enough time and I don't even have a good idea nor a starting point. This is the problem:

> Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be a convergent series. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ is also convergent.

Thanks for your kind and nice answers, I'm sure a good tip or starting point will suffice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n} \leq \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \left(a_n + \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's not a hint, that's $\textbf{the Hint}$. That kind of inequalities (those obtained by squaring expresions) are really common and I haven't got used to them.

Comment: BTW, this is a duplicate. Now, after I've looked a lot for this question and I've decided to post it by myself, I discover that.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374392/convergence-of-the-series-sum-a-n-implies-the-convergence-of-sum-frac-sqr?rq=1

Comment: Sir, what about the convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ when $\sum a_n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ converges? Can we use the same concept of means?