# Convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n }{\sqrt{n}}$ given that $\sum a_n^2$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

**Hypothesis**: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ also converges.

I'm looking for a counterexample (or proof) to this claim.
The only assumption is $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/992789/916261) it was proved that convergence of $\sum a_n^2$ implies convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^p}$ for $p=1$. I noticed it can be easily generalised for $p>\frac{1}{2}$ since:
$$ 0 \leq (a_n - \frac{1}{n^p})^2 = a_n^2 - 2\frac{a_n}{n^p} + \frac{1}{n^{2p}} \implies \frac{a_n}{n^p} \leq \frac{1}{2}(a_n^2 + \frac{1}{n^{2p}}) $$
On the other hand, for $p<\frac{1}{2}$ there is a counterexample: $a_n = \frac{1}{n^{1-p}}$. But it doesn't apply to $p= \frac{1}{2}$, since then $\sum a_n^2 = \sum \frac{1}{n}$, which diverges.
So no p-series can be a counter and also Cauchy-Schwarz doesn't help.

Comment: I think you want $a_n \geq 0$, not merely $a_n \in \mathbf R$. An inequality $x_n \leq y_n$ for all (large) $n$ and convergence of $\sum y_n$ doesn't force convergence of $\sum x_n$ without some lower bound on $x_n$, typically $x_n \geq 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log n}$. Then $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n^2 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$ which converges by Cauchy's condensation test, but $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$$ and this diverges, again by Cauchy's condensation test.

Comment: I was just about to write up that example and then saw you posted it.  Another way to explain convergence and divergence is with the integral test, which more people are familiar with than the condensation test: $\int_2^\infty dx/(x(\log x)^2) = -(1/\log x)|_2^\infty  = 1/\log 2 < \infty$ and $\int_2^\infty dx/(x\log x) = \log\log x|_2^\infty = \infty$.

Comment: @KCd Right, thanks, I added the indexes to make it clear we start from $n=2$. By the way when I studied Calculus we didn't cover integration yet (that came in the following course) and we used the condensation test a lot.

Comment: You learned about infinite series in calculus *before* integration?  Wow. Was there a textbook used in that course?

Comment: Well, that was quick. I'm familiar with Cauchy's condestation test so it's okay, also covered it way before integration in my analysis course.

Comment: @KCd Yeah, we studied sequences, then infinite series (of numbers), then functions and derivatives. In the second course we had integration and series of functions. The textbook was not in English but I think I remember seeing the same approach in some other texts.. I'll write down the name if I find it.

Comment: @Figment Whenever you're looking for something that seems "right on the border" between $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$ for $p>1$ it's good to consider stuff like $\sum \frac{1}{n(\log n)^{\alpha}}$ or even $\sum \frac{1}{n \log n \log{\log n}}$ etc.

Comment: @Figment where (at least in what country) are you studying analysis with series being taught way before integration?

Comment: Oh!  That's an analysis course for people who almost certain have already seen calculus before in some form. I thought these were somehow courses teaching infinite series to an audience that genuinely had never seen integration before in previous math classes.  Rudin lacks motivation for many topics, so I think it'd be hard to use by someone totally unfamiliar with calculus even if *logically* that background is not required.

Comment: @Snaw an interesting counterexample to the idea of using single logarithms to interpolate between constant growth and growth slower than $n^\varepsilon$ for each $\varepsilon > 0$ is that the divisor function $d(n)$ satisfies $d(n) = O(n^\varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ but $d(n) \not= O((\log n)^k)$ for some $k$.  In fact, $d(n) = O(n^{c/\log\log n})$ for some $c$ (take $c > \log 2$ and you're okay).

Comment: @KCd That's a very interesting example, thanks for that. About the course: it's a first year course for math majors. We see integrals in high school but in a very non-rigorous manner (just quoting the rules for integration while implicitly using the fundamental theorem of calculus, no definition other than "it calculates areas"). I think the difference lies in that in the USA a freshman would take introductory courses in college before they pick their major, right? In most (I believe) of Europe you pick your major when you enroll, so the first year courses would be just for math majors.

Comment: @Snaw yes, that's right.  In the US you don't *need* to declare your major as part of enrolling and typically you have to do that by the end of the 2nd year or start of the 3rd year. Of course there are students who know right away what they're interested in and declare very soon. The system is also flexible in that you are allowed to *change* majors. Someone can come in wanting to study physics and a year later switch to biology or history.