# The indefinite integral of an $L^1$ function has a convergent series of Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in L^1([0,2\pi])$ be a $2\pi$-periodic function with $\hat f(0)=0$ and $\hat f(\vert n\vert)=-\hat f(-\vert n\vert)\geq 0$. Define $F(t)=\int_0^t f(x)dx$. I know that F iscontinuous, $2\pi$-periodic function and $\hat F(n)=\frac{\hat f(n)}{in}$ if $n\neq 0$.

I want to prove that $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\hat f(n)}{n}<\infty$.

How to prove that?

Comment: If $f\in L^2$, then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality yields this, as in [Convergence of the series $\sum a_n$ implies the convergence of $\sum \frac{\sqrt a_n}{n}$, if $a_n>0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374392/convergence-of-the-series-sum-a-n-implies-the-convergence-of-sum-frac-sqr). If it's only in $L^1$, I'm not convinced the result is true...

Comment: Just to be clear: do you really mean $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\hat f(n)}{n}<\infty$, or should it be $\sum_{n\geq 1} \left|\frac{\hat f(n)}{n} \right|<\infty$?

Comment: I mean first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $F$ is continuous and of bounded variation because
$$
                       V_{a}^{b}(F) = \int_{a}^{b}|f(t)|dt.
$$
Therefore the Fourier series for $F$ converges pointwise everywhere to $F$ (in fact it must converge uniformly.) In particular,
$$
              F(0) = \lim_N\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{F}(n)=2\lim_N\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\hat{f}(n)}{in}.
$$